# Antivirus in Ubuntu?

Tags: malware, antivirus

I have recently made a switch to Ubuntu from Windows just because Windows is more prone to viruses. We all know Ubuntu isn't also 100% immune to viruses/intruders. Is there any need of installing antivirus in Ubuntu Linux just to be on the safer side?

Comment: off course **no** unless or until you did something really suspicious on purpose. You can still download stacer as an optimizer , which will also help in security purposes.

Comment: "We all know Ubuntu isn't also 100% immune to viruses"  There are currently zero active virusses. Rootkits are more of a problem.